# last row of cardview is not showing in all devices

Tags: android, android-cardview

I am working in an android app ,In this I have cardview ,What is my issue is When I run the app it working nice but the last row of `cardview` is not showing correctly .

I  checked in several emulator devices it shows the same in all devices.

Please help me to fix this issue.

> cardview.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    cardview:cardElevation="5dp"
    cardview:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    cardview:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mReminder_Image_Id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="#ffffff"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mReminder_Text_Id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#2d2d2d"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:text="Reminder texts"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

> fragment_reminders.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Fragments.Reminders">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Reminders"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/tab_background"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/mRecyclerView_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/Conslayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"

        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:layoutMode="opticalBounds"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"

        app:itemBackground="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/color_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/color_selector" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Issue is in Activity layout where you inflate fragment. Post your activity xml too

Comment: @Khemraj I inflate the cardview in fragments_reminders.xml .

Comment: I am saying about your xml where you have used BottomNavigationView

Comment: Maybe you could just use a `ScrollView` instead of a `LinearLayout` ?

Comment: @Khemraj I have updated the activity_main.xml please take a look

Comment: @Nofix I tried it but it's not working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your activity main layout by this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"

        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:layoutMode="opticalBounds"

        app:itemBackground="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/color_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/color_selector"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Explanation :**

Your `BottomNavigationView` was overlapping your `FrameLayout`. I wrapped your view with `LinearLayout` instead of `ContraintLayout` to use weight, just gave `FrameLayout` weight 1, so it occupy available space above bottom navigation.